# Can I say "when it comes to the stage of..."?

Tags: phrases

As a result, the two of us who started off being very poor in programming wound up writing and designing the main structure of a website called “team work”. I continued to be in charge of  technology when it *came to* the stage of APP exploration.

I mean when the main part of the website has been completed, we started to design APP. Usually "when it come to.." is followed by a specific event, not by a word related with time. So I am not sure at all whether it is natural to say "when it comes to the stage of..."

Answer (score 0):

It's okay, but…

While it's logical to use "when it came to" to refer to either an event or a period in time, it has an idiomatic use referring to an activity:

> I continued to be in charge of technology when it came to exploring APP.

(I'm not sure what you mean by *APP* here, so I'm not sure if "exploring APP" makes sense).

A close relative, "when we came to", allows a greater focus on how you are talking about your experiences:

> I continued to be in charge of technology when we came to the stage of APP exploration.

Or perhaps more punch comes with:

> I continued to be in charge of technology when we came to explore APP.